# Angular <mat-select> component is not working on a FormGroup

Tags: angular, angular-material, material-design, angular9

I'm trying to use  inside a formGroup but although it builds the component and I can navigate through options, I couldn't select any of them. When the page is loaded I can see this error :

> ERROR TypeError: "this._selectionModel.onChange is undefined"

Here's my component.ts :

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-agent',
  templateUrl: './agent.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./agent.component.css']
})
export class AgentComponent implements OnInit {

  agents = [];
  durationInSeconds = 5;
  statusList = ['AVAILABLE', 'NOT_AVAILABLE'];
  agentForm = new FormGroup ({
    name: new FormControl(),
    status: new FormControl(this.statusList[0]),
  });
  searchForm = new FormGroup(
    {key: new FormControl()}
  );

  constructor(private agentService: AgentService) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.getAll();
  }

  filter(): void {
    if (this.searchForm.value.key) {
      this.getOne();
    } else {
      this.getAll();
    }
  }

  save(): void {
    this.agentService.save(new AgentData(this.agentForm.value.name, this.agentForm.value.status)).subscribe((data) => {
      this.agentForm.value.name = data.name;
      this.agentForm.value.status = data.status;
    }
    );
  }
}
```

And this is the component html part :

```
        <form [formGroup]="agentForm" (submit)="save()">
          <table class="form-group" style="width: 100%; ">
            <div class="row" >
              <mat-form-field style="width: 100%; ">
                <mat-label>Agent name</mat-label>
                <input matInput placeholder="Ex. fferchichi" formControlName="name">
              </mat-form-field>
            </div>

            <div class="row">
              <mat-form-field style="width: 100%;">
                <mat-label>Status</mat-label>
                <mat-select formControlName="status">
                  <mat-option *ngFor="let status of statusList" [value]="status">
                    {{status | labelit}}
                  </mat-option>
                </mat-select>
                <mat-error *ngIf="agentForm.hasError('required')">Please choose a Status</mat-error>
              </mat-form-field>
            </div>

            <div class="row" style="text-align: right;">
              <input type="submit" class="btn btn-default" value="Save"/>
            </div>

          </table>
        </form>
```

It feels like the binding with formControl is read-only but I can't find out why or how to fix it.

Answer (score 1):

According to [Angular.io documentation for FormControl](https://angular.io/api/forms/AbstractControl#value) the 'value' property is readonly.

you should use the formcontrol.setValue() method to change the value of a formcontrol

Comment: I also tried the example suggested by the material page :
https://material.angular.io/components/select/overview#

Section :  Form field features 
But still the same problem. It feels like I am missing something but I can't see what it is.

Comment: this.agentForm.controls['name'].setValue(data.name); this.agentForm.controls['status'].setValue(data.status)'

Answer (score 0):

you cannot simply assign values to formcontrol using '=' symbol,
You have to options, i.e., eitheir you have to use setValue method or patchValue method,
I'd suggest you to use patchValue method because, when you use setValue method you have to change every formcontrol in your form.
so you try something like this...

```
this.searchForm.patchValue({
    name: data.name,
    status: data.status
});`
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and I fix it using native select and adding the matNativeControl.

```
<mat-form-field style="width: 100%;">
   <mat-label>Status</mat-label>
   <select matNativeControl formControlName="status">
      <option *ngFor="let status of statusList" [value]="status">
         {{status | labelit}}
      </option>
   </select>
   <mat-error *ngIf="agentForm.hasError('required')">Please choose a Status</mat-error>
</mat-form-field>
```